# Have vim not caring about the capslock state in normal mode

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, vim, vi

I would like to know if it is possible (and if yes, how) to have vim (or another vi-like editor, really. Changing from vim to another one would not annoy me that much, as long as the editor is usable in a terminal and have modes.) ignoring the CAPS_LOCK state when not writing actual text (this mean, not in edition mode and not in command mode - I guess it's the name of the one where you ask vim to quit, save, etc - ).

It is probably easy to remap the key something else (there are tons of pages explaining that after all) but I use this key for it's real role often enough (yes, I do use constants a lot in my code, and no I do not enjoy needing to waste a finger on any shift key while writing them) so it's not what I'm asking for.
I could also remap 'J' (for example) to something else and all lowercase keys to their uppercase key, but again, not what I'm asking for (plus, it would probably be a horrible mess, and I already consider that configuring vim is a hell).
To keep the 'J' example, I would like vim to only understand it as 'J' if any SHIFT key is actually pressed, and not if CAPS_LOCK_STATE is true.

Is it possible?

Comment: I understand what you want here. It would be very useful. I did a little research but I couldn't find any solution for this yet.

Comment: Maybe it's simply not possible.